# проверка версии pdo и методы

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Доброго времени суток!
Новичок в PDO, да и с php шапочное знакомство. 
Пытаюсь положить значения в базу данных. Код:

```
$sql = "UPDATE goods SET (title, category, description, price)  VALUES (?,?,?,?) WHERE id = $id"; 
        $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $pdo->bindParam("sssi", $data -> title, $data -> category, $data -> description, $data -> price);
        $pdo->execute();
```

Выскакивает ошибка [image: пробовал также и $pdo -> bind_param]

пробовал также и $pdo -> bind_param, там же выскакивает ошибка. 
Еще вопросик, в $data у меня хранится массив вида "ключ" -> "значение". Ключи совпадают с названиями таблиц в БД. Как их оптом положить в БД с помощью PDO?.

Answer (score 1):

Вы вызываете bindParam на объекте PDO, а не на объекте подготавливаемого выражения

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statment->bindParam(...);
^^^^^^^^^
```

Кроме того, вы неправильно используете bindParam, он предназначен для установки только одного параметра

Comment: а такой вопрос, если у меня сохранён массив вида ключ -> значение, причем ключи соответствуют названиям полей в БД, как их оптом передать?

Comment: а куда надо применять bindParam? проверил функцией/методом, не знаю как в php это называется,  get_class_methods('pdo'), там нет методов bind_param, равно как и bindParam. Что же всё так сложно((. Можно как-то проверить версию PDO и методы, которые возможны?

Comment: @ТобакаловКаниет прочитайте, пожалуйста, первую строчку моего ответа. Там прямо сказано, что это все должно вызывать не у pdo.