# update значений в БД через pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Привет!
Есть такая таблица: [image: таблица]

При добавлении/редактировании строки таблицы, я передаю в php массив в котором содержатся следующие поля:

```
[id] => 1
[title] => asus zenfone 3
[category] => Мобильные телефоны
[description] => Мобильный телефон, анонсированный в 2016 году. Модель отличается внушительной емкостью батареи, что позволяет работать смартфону продолжительное время. 

[price] => 12450.5
[action] => edit
```

Передаю через XMLHTTPRequest.
Как вы сами понимаете, именование ключей в объекте и в таблице совпадает.
Кроме 'action', для особо умных, естественно я удалю его на стороне сервера, после отправки запроса на обновление данных в БД.
На стороне сервера я получаю данные. Вопрос в том, как их оптом закинуть в базу данных, используя PDO?

Comment: А как вы пробовали?

Comment: Так пробовал - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/674068/проверка-версии-pdo-и-методы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я делаю так ($item - ваш массив):

```
// Подключение БД
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->exec("set names utf8");
// Подготовка запроса
$sql = "UPDATE ваша_таблица SET title=:title, category=:category, description=:description, price:=price where id = :id";
$table = $db->prepare($sql);
unset(item['action']);
//Вставка данных
$table->execute($item);
```